# get full phone number from intl_phone_field package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to get full number from `IntlPhoneField` (package `intl_phone_field` )

I use controller to get number. but it not includes country code,

```
        IntlPhoneField(
                    disableLengthCheck: true,
                    controller: phoneNumberCon,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Phone Number',
                    ),
        ),
```

I tried,

```
            String input = phoneNumberCon.text.trim();
            String finalone = "${phone.countrycode} + $input";
```

It not working because `phone.countrycode` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onChanged` method and try to pass out its value like this, First define new variable like this:

```
String fullPhone = '';
```

then try this:

```
IntlPhoneField(
   disableLengthCheck: true,
   controller: phoneNumberCon,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
       hintText: 'Phone Number',
   ),
   onChanged: (phone) {
      print(phone.completeNumber);
      setState(() {
         fullPhone = phone.completeNumber;
      });
   },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Have you checked the capitalisation required by the library?

You have written:

```
String finalone = "${phone.countrycode} + $input";
```

Should it be this?

```
String finalone = "${phone.countryCode} + $input";
```